# Python Twitter bot, Tweepy 4.10.1 gives Traceback error and tweepy.errors.Forbidden 403

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-oauth

I made sure that all the keys and secrets are correct, but I'm just not sure that I'm getting it.

(**I HAVE ELEVATED ACCESS**)
[image]

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdmUhQnPToM) tutorial on YouTube.

This is the Python code:

```py
import tweepy

api_key = "XXXXX"
api_secret = "XXXXX"
bearer_token = r"XXXXX"
access_token = "XXXXX"
access_token_secret = "XXXXX"

# "XXXX" is just a placeholder, for when i post to Stack Overflow

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


client.create_tweet(text="Hello Twitter")
```

And this is the terminal error:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed it was...

When I used to have Essential access and generated the access token and secret, it was in "read-only". And even after getting elevated access and regenerating, it kept generating tokens still in "read-only".

So I just set it as "read and write" and now it works fine. That's what fixed it. Such a small thing.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-403-forbidden-error-with-api:

If you have Essential access to the Twitter API, you won’t be able to access Twitter API v1.1. This includes all API methods and Stream.

You can use Twitter API v2 with Client or apply for Elevated access.

See the [Twitter API access levels and versions documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#Access) for more information.

Comment: I already have elevated access.

Comment: Oh, i applied today. Maybe an hour ago?.... Thank you. I'll check back tomorrow and see if it works. Didn't know it takes time.

Comment: Hmm, probably should be working by now. Double check your keys/secrets? (You may also have to regenerate them after having gotten elevated access) @SlobodanBajić

Comment: Actually, It looks like the access token and secret keep being generated with "read-only" access. I changed it to read and write, and now it works. Thanks for your help. I missed such a small thing. @AlpaccaSnack